# How to pass parameters to Nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget, blazor, razor-pages

I have made Nuget package from Blazor Hosted app.The problem is that I don't know how to get/pass parameters from others project to consume it in my package.I see that I have App.razor and MainLayot.
App.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </LayoutView>
</NotFound>
```

If I want to make something like this.I want to use my packege like this.

```
<App Options="options" />
 @*Here I want to pass parameter to my package.*@
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass parameters to your package? This question does not really describe what you're trying to achieve. However, I can tell you that you cannot pass parameters to a nuget package! That is not what nuget is about. You install the package and the code/dlls are consumed into your project.

Comment: Because the other project that will use the package has internationalization and themes. When a user changes the theme or language in the main project this should happen in the package, which is like a subproject and stands in a separate tab. I did this in Angular but I don't know with Blazor .The thing is that the package is in a separate repo and uses different bases has its own rest.

Comment: You won't be passing parameters 'to the package'. You can call methods and use classes that are available as a result of consuming the package. When you call these methods you can pass parameters. You can access any public classes, methods and properties from the assemblies included in your package.

Comment: Neither here nor there, but why are you even trying to use nuget packages for what appears to just be an internal sub-project.  Why not just use a project?

Comment: It is very simple. You can add it like a Parameter to your component. Don't forget to declare it in code scope.